# Where to put API key file in Laravel

Tags: php, api, laravel

I am using Google API in Laravel. I am following the Google Developer [guide](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/quickstart/php). They suggest storing a `.json` key and then calling it like this:

```
define('CLIENT_SECRET_PATH', __DIR__ . '/client_secret.json');
...
function getClient() {
    ...
    $client->setAuthConfigFile(CLIENT_SECRET_PATH);
    ...
}
```

**My question is:** where is the correct place to store the file in Laravel?
And What is the correct way to call it?

Obviously, I don't want it to be publicly visible... Thanks ahead for any suggestions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct place to put api keys is in the .env file.

It will automatically set anything in there as environment variables so in order to retrieve the api key, you'd do the following `env('GOOGLE_API_KEY')`.

The .env file is the perfect place because of its ease of use as well as the ability to keep all settings within from source control.  (You don't want files stored on github etc... to contain API keys and credentials.)

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. It works great if I'm using `GOOGLE_API_KEY`.
And what if I wanted to use a file from OAuth 2.0? like a `.p12` file or a `.json` file?

Comment: Then use those files instead?  I'm not sure what you are asking.

Comment: And what is the most convenient directory to place these files?

Comment: Usually in the root directory for your app.  Laravel should already come with the .env file in place.  If you are using something besides Laravel, you would need the following https://packagist.org/packages/vlucas/phpdotenv